# Проверка делимости числа на цело

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm

```
fun main()
{
    var n = 100
    for (i in 1..n)
    {
        if (i / 3 == ) // тут в if должен быть параметр, который допускает только целочисленное значение 
        {
            print("$i ")
        }

        if (i / 5 == ) // тут в if должен быть параметр, который допускает только целочисленное значение 
        {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Я написал код, который высчитывает числа, которые делятся на 3 и на 5 без остатка, но не на 3 и 5 одновременно. Я не знаю, как реализовать параметры if, чтобы на выходе я получил целочисленное значение. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то подскажет.

P.S. Я новичек, поэтому строго не судите =)

Comment: !(((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Думаю что так

```
fun main () {
var n = 100

 for (i in 1..n) {
     
    if(i % 3 == 0) // тут в if должен быть параметр, который допускает только целочисленное значение 
  {
      print("$i ")
        
          }
    
  if   (i % 5 == 0 ) // тут в if должен быть параметр, который допускает только целочисленное значение 

   { print(i)
      
   }

   }       
}
```

Comment: А что за минус можно как-то пояснить?